# Using nested reduce in Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, functional-programming, reduce

I have an array which contains an arrays of `Double`, like in the screenshot:

[image]

My goal is to get the sum of the multiplication of the `Double` elements of each array. It means, I want to multiply all elements of each array then, in my case, I will have 3 values so I get the sum of them.

I want to use `reduce`, `flatMap` ? or any elegant solution.

What I have tried ?

```
totalCombinations.reduce(0.0) { $0 + ($1[0]*$1[1]*$1[2])  }
```

but this work only when I know the size of the arrays that contains the doubles.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Given these values

```
let lists: [[Double]] = [[1.1, 2.2, 3.3], [4.4, 5.5, 6.6]]
```

let's take a look at several possible approaches

### Solution #1

```
let sum =  lists.reduce(0) { $0 + $1.reduce(1, combine: *) }
```

### Solution #2

If you define this extension

```
extension SequenceType where Generator.Element == Double {
    var product : Double { return reduce(1.0, combine: *) }
}
```

then you can write

```
let sum = lists.reduce(0) { $0 + $1.product }
```

### Solution #3

With the extension defined above you can also write

```
let sum = lists.map { $0.product }.reduce(0, combine:+)
```

### Solution #4

If we define these 2 postfix operators

```
postfix operator +>{}
postfix func +>(values:[Double]) -> Double {
    return values.reduce(0, combine: +)
}

postfix operator *>{}
postfix func *>(values:[Double]) -> Double {
    return values.reduce(1, combine: *)
}
```

we can write

```
lists.map(*>)+>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can write something like this:

```
let totalCombinations: [[Double]] = [
    [2.4,1.45,3.35],
    [2.4,1.45,1.42],
    [2.4,3.35,1.42],
    [1.45,3.35,1.42],
]

let result = totalCombinations.reduce(0.0) {$0 + $1.reduce(1.0) {$0 * $1} }

print(result) //->34.91405
```

But I'm not sure it's "elegant" or not.

Comment: Not sure if considered more elegant in this case, but you can pass the `*` operator to `reduce` directly (`$1.reduce(1, combine: *)`)

Comment: @Hamish, good point. But it's already included in appzYourLife's answer. So, I think I'm late.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this is what you're looking for

```
let a = [1.0, 2.0, 3.0]
let b = [4.0, 5.0, 6.0]
let c = [7.0, 8.0, 9.0, 10.0]

let d = [a, b, c]

let sum = d.reduce(0.0) { $0 + $1.reduce(1.0) {$0 * $1}}
print(sum) // prints 5166.0
```